# Matlab R2014 issue with saving colormap from colormapeditor

Tags: matlab, colormap

Simple question: in `Matlab R2013, Win7(64)` (actually always it was like that) after changes made in `colormapeditor` one can copy the values of `colormap` just by typing `colormap` or `get(gcf,'Colormap')` or similar. But in the version `R2014` I cannot do this - no matter what I change in `colormapeditor`, I get the same default `colormap`. See this in Matlab command line:

```
img=surf(peaks)
colormapeditor
```

(now, change for instance the limit colors to red). Now use:

```
colormap
get(gcf,'Colormap')
```

you got the same default UNCHANGED `colormap`. However if you close `colormapeditor` and invoke it again it remembers changed colors.

What I'm doing wrong? Is this :New MATLAB Graphics System" responsible for that?

Thank you for help.

Yacek.

PS:
The same states if you use `fig=figure` first and than try `get(fig,'Colormap')` or `fig.Colormap` etc. The command `colormapeditor` remembers changes, but one cannot save them.

Comment: You are rigth... Additionally, colormap(fig) does also return the default one.

Comment: If I hit "Apply" in the colormapeditor, the resulting colormap is different (verified with `get(gcf,'Colormap')` before and after).  Can you ensure you doing that?

Comment: I've tried with "Apply" as well and get(gcf,'Colormap'), but still the colormap is the default one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the colormap is now associated with the axes rather than the figure.  So,

cmap = colormap(gca);

will retrieve the map you're looking for.

Comment: Yes! It solves problem. I got also a message from Matlab support. They poropose basically the same: make 'axhandle=subplot(1,1,1)' and then one can play with 'colormapeditor' and see the results by  'colormap(axhandle)'.